# Pure CSS mobile menu: Unable to close

Tags: css

**How does one close this pure CSS mobile menu when clicking on the menu links?** I tried wrapping them in `<label for="nav-collapse"><a>...</a></label>` like the close button (which works) but to no avail.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwEBaM

based on http://www.scottohara.me/article/morph-button-updated.html

```css
 *, *::after, *::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: arial;
  line-height: 2;
  margin: 0; }

body {
  background: #444;
  overflow-x: hidden; }

p {
  margin-bottom: 24px; }
  p:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0; }

.content {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
  padding: 20px; }

.invis {
  height: 1px;
  left: -999px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -999px;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 1px; }

.main-base {
  background: #eee;
  left: 0px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all .3s; }

  .main-base header, .main-base footer {
    background: #888;
    color: #fff; }

footer a {
  color: #fff; }

.nav-side {
  background: #56cee8;
  color: #fff;
  top: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  height: 60px;
  left: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: fixed;
  transition: all .3s;
  width: 60px;
  z-index: 2; }

.menu-list {
  height: 0%;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  transition: all .3s; }
  .menu-list a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    color: #222;
    display: block;
    padding: 12px 8px;
    text-decoration: none; }
    .menu-list a:hover {
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }

.btn-label {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0; }
  .btn-label .top {
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    left: 12px;
    right: 12px;
  }
  .btn-label .middle {
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 22px;
    left: 12px;
    right: 12px;
  }
  .btn-label .bottom {
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 32px;
    left: 12px;
    right: 12px;
  }
  .btn-label .label {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  #nav-expand:checked + .nav-side .btn-label {
    display: none;
  }

.close {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 15px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: hand;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff; }
  #nav-expand:checked + .nav-side .close {
    display: block;
  }

#nav-expand:checked + .nav-side {
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px; }
  #nav-expand:checked + .nav-side .menu-list {
    height: 100%; }
  #nav-expand:checked + .nav-side .btn-label {
    color: transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 20px; }
  #nav-expand:checked + .nav-side + .main-base {
    left: 200px; }
  #nav-collapse + .main-base {
    left: 200px; }
  #nav-collapse + .main-base > .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .3s; }
  #nav-collapse:checked + .main-base {
    left: 0; }
  #nav-collapse:checked + .main-base > .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    opacity: 0; }
```

```html
 <div class="page">

    <input type="radio" id="nav-expand" name="nav" class="invis" />
    <nav class="nav-side">
      <label for="nav-collapse" class="close">
        &times;
      </label>
      <label for="nav-expand" class="btn-label">
        <span class="top"></span><span class="middle"></span><span class="bottom"></span><span class="label">MENU</span>
      </label>

      <ul class="menu-list">
        <li>
          <label for="nav-collapse">
            <a href="#!" title="descriptive title">
              Link Label
            </a>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label for="nav-collapse">
            <a href="#!" title="descriptive title">
              ಠ_ಠ Link Label
            </a>
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <input type="radio" id="nav-collapse" name="nav" checked="checked" class="invis" />
    <main class="main-base" role="main">

      <header class="header-base" role="banner">
        <div class="content">
          <h1>
            Display Sidebar/Settings on Click/Press of Icon
          </h1>
        </div>
      </header>

      <article>
        <div class="content">
          <p>
            Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet filet mignon prosciutto ham hock boudin pork chop swine shoulder beef. Flank andouille ground round strip steak pork bacon venison ham hock, tongue turducken. Venison jowl hamburger salami bacon capicola. Chuck ribeye sirloin spare ribs, venison beef t-bone prosciutto swine strip steak. Chuck jowl spare ribs tenderloin prosciutto. Pancetta pork chop venison bacon short ribs porchetta. Short loin short ribs kielbasa biltong t-bone tail brisket porchetta pork pork loin chicken.
          </p>
          <p>
            Pork belly meatball sirloin ribeye pork loin meatloaf. Tongue kielbasa chuck sausage, turducken jerky hamburger t-bone fatback frankfurter pork loin pig venison tail. Sirloin tri-tip kevin shankle salami doner jerky capicola leberkas tongue drumstick. Tongue turkey prosciutto salami tri-tip. Shank doner sirloin landjaeger pancetta beef ribs.
          </p>
          <p>
            Frankfurter pork loin short ribs andouille kevin. T-bone tail pig chuck prosciutto brisket. Landjaeger tail fatback beef porchetta, biltong shoulder turkey shankle kevin jowl pancetta brisket pork belly boudin. Short loin tenderloin swine, hamburger bresaola rump shank ground round ham kielbasa chicken pancetta capicola. Boudin chicken frankfurter, pig kielbasa flank ball tip. Corned beef pastrami landjaeger, meatloaf flank shankle pig meatball chuck pork loin swine.
          </p>
          <p>
            Pork belly meatball sirloin ribeye pork loin meatloaf. Tongue kielbasa chuck sausage, turducken jerky hamburger t-bone fatback frankfurter pork loin pig venison tail. Sirloin tri-tip kevin shankle salami doner jerky capicola leberkas tongue drumstick. Tongue turkey prosciutto salami tri-tip. Shank doner sirloin landjaeger pancetta beef ribs.
          </p>
          <p>
            Frankfurter pork loin short ribs andouille kevin. T-bone tail pig chuck prosciutto brisket. Landjaeger tail fatback beef porchetta, biltong shoulder turkey shankle kevin jowl pancetta brisket pork belly boudin. Short loin tenderloin swine, hamburger bresaola rump shank ground round ham kielbasa chicken pancetta capicola. Boudin chicken frankfurter, pig kielbasa flank ball tip. Corned beef pastrami landjaeger, meatloaf flank shankle pig meatball chuck pork loin swine.
          </p>
        </div>
      </article>

      <footer>
        <div class="content">
          <p>
            oh bai
          </p>
        </div>
      </footer>

      <label for="nav-collapse" class="overlay"></label>
    </main>

  </div>
```

Comment: Please only post the relevant information. If you have to post this much code you have not narrowed down the problem enough.

Comment: instead of using a checkbox to initiate the showing / hiding of the
 navigation and pushing the page over, we’re instead using radio
 buttons.
 
 Switching to the radio buttons allowed us to initiate the overlay
 effect, which is just a <label> styled through the class .overlay to
 mimic an overlay -- From the site

Comment: @below9k it *is* using radio buttons.

Comment: @DustinPoissant it's a CSS-heavy solution. I'm not really sure what else to remove. There's some dummy text there, but come on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the link takes the click event and does not pass it to the label.

If you wrap the label inside the anchor, the problem is reversed. The menu collapses but the link is not followed.

I don't think you will have any luck with this.

There's another way to toggle a menu in pure CSS. It does not involve custom markup like for the radio boxes but has other drawbacks.

The idea is to use an anchor on the open menu link.

```css
.page-wrap #open-menu {
  display: block;
}
.page-wrap #close-menu {
  display: none;
}
.page-wrap #open-menu:target {
  display: block;
}
.page-wrap #open-menu:target + #close-menu {
  display: none;
}
.page-wrap #close-menu:target {
  display: block;
}
.page-wrap #close-menu:target + #open-menu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-wrap">
  <a id="close-menu" href="#open-menu">Close</a> 
  <a id="open-menu" href="#close-menu">Open</a> 
</div>
```

See adapted solution for original question : http://codepen.io/manuszep/pen/NPyWqV

### There are drawbacks :

As the solution relies on anchors to trigger the menu, the browser will scroll to that anchor when you click it. This is something you may not want.

Another issue, if you use that solution for other applications, is that clicking any other anchor on the page will deactivate the current one.

And finally, you can have only one active anchor at a time.

Comment: Cool, but is there no way to use this with Scott o'Hara's solution? It's a pretty famous solution and it pretty much trumps every other pure CSS mobile menu I've come across.

Comment: I added a solution in CodePen

Comment: Cheers mate - that's freakin' awesome!

Comment: While I got you here do check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28462571/pure-css-mobile-menu-hiding-content-while-contracting regarding the same test case :)

Comment: You mention this alternative method has drawbacks - what are they?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention them. Updated the post.

Comment: I'm in a situation where one of my menu link needs to be `<a href="#foo">` so it can take me to `<h1 id="foo">` inside `<main>` - is this not possible with the current implementation? Unfortunately JS is not an option.

Comment: Mark, It's possible but the menu will close as soon as you click on that link (which may be what you want btw).

Comment: That is indeed what I want, however something seems to be preventing the default behavior. `<a href="#foo">` outside the menu doesn't work either: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GgxrxX

Comment: You should remove the exclamation mark from the href : <a href="#test"> instead of <a href="#!test">

Answer (score 1):

I was working on AMP[https://www.ampproject.org/] and I needed a pure css for the website I was working on and I came up with this. [target: mobile devices]

check this out : https://jsfiddle.net/salkamoses/ov1mkasm/

```
<a href="#something">
<div class="menubutton">
<em class="em1"></em><em class="em2"></em><em class="em3"></em>
</div>
</a>


<div id="something">
<a href="#hide">
<div class="menubuttonclose">
X
</div>
</a>

<p>menu header</p>

<p>menu1</p>

<p>menu2</p>
</div>
```

css:

```
    #something {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    left: 8px;
}
#hide {
  display:none;
}
#hide:target {
  display:none;
}
#something:target {
  display: block;
}

.em1 {
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: #e81c28;
    }
    .em2 {
    margin-top: 5px;
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: #e81c28;
    }
    .em3 {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    height: 2px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: #e81c28;
    }

 .menubuttonclose
 {
    background-color: white;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
```